# JQuery val(), text() and html() all return an empty String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a probably minor issue but somehow am not able to fix it since I am sitting here since 2 hours without a fix.

I have written a little helper tool with google maps using node.js express on serverside, javascript / jQuery on clientside and jade as HTML-template engine.
I wanted to dynamically adjust the GPS-radius around my google-maps-pins via a user input but I always get the empty string as return.

HTML:

```
<form id="formTrackedBus" action="/trackBus" method="post" name="trackedBus">
    <input id="asdf" type="text" placeholder="Type in radius around the bus">
    <button id="btnSubmit" onclick="getRadius()" value="submit" type="submit">submit</button>
```

The part of jQuery where `getRadius();` is invoked looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
    $(function getRadius(){
        var radius = $('#asdf').val();
        alert("Radius: "+radius);
    });
...  
});
```

Does enybody see a problem at this? `.text()` and `.html()` also return the empty string. I really don't get the mistake, I already renamed the `id` to "asdf" to be sure that it isn't a dublicate id...

More explicitely:

I am handling the google-maps-stuff inside my `$(document).ready`-block. There I need the radius via user-input to adjust the radius of my marker dynamically.

I tried it with a global variable at first, which looked like this

```
var radius;
function getRadius() {
    radius = document.getElementById('asdf');
    alert(radius.value); 
}
```

This worked fine. But when I tried to use this global *radius* inside my `$(document).ready`-block, it didn't work since it returned *undefined* everytime:

```
var radius;
function getRadius() {
    radius = document.getElementById('asdf');
    alert(radius.value); 
}

$(document).ready(function () {

$(function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        // center Aachen at the map
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.7753455, 6.083886799999959),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});

// doesn't look nice, but using setInterval(addMarker(), 5000); didn't work
// since curiously this way addMarker was just fired once...
setInterval(function addMarker() {

    var newLat = 0;
    var newLang = 0;


// jQuery AJAX call for JSON
        $.getJSON('/busdata/busCoordinates', function (data) {$.each(data, function () {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(this.latitude, this.longitude),
                title: 'MarkerNo: '+pollingRound+'\n'+
                    'VehicleID: '+this.vehicleID.toString()+'\n'+
                    'Update Time:'+this.time
            });
            var busRadius;
            var circleOptions = {
                strokeColor: "FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: "#FF0000",
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                map: map,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(this.latitude, this.longitude),
                radius: radius
            };
    };
```

So how am I able to get this `var radius` in my `circleOptions`?

Comment: so after you enter some text in the asdf input and then click the button you get empty value?

Comment: It's probably not related to your problem, but you don't need to wrap a $(callback) inside a $(document).ready(). Either alone will only run the code on DOMContentReady. And neither actually has to be used in this case; this code will never be invoked before the DOM is ready.

Comment: Once you remove the function definition from inside the `document.ready` and remove the outer jQuery call `$(...)`, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/c6Lxom8w/

Comment: Well, the query-wrap was more a trial and error try.
At first I tried to solve this with an (ugly, I know) global value *var radius* and saving the user input via
document.getElementById('asdf');

But then I could not use it at my jQuery-block where I need it, since I am handling the whole googlemaps-stuff in the $(document).ready-block

Comment: Yes, tried this already, but than I can't get the value in my $(document).ready block as I have written before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
The problem didn't lie in the code itself but in the program-flow.
Everytime when I click on submit I reload the `index.js` so my global `var radius` got overwritten with its default value again since my page reloaded. 
Therefore `getRadius()` has been invoked and actually **did** overwrite the global `val radius` but **before** the page has reloaded again and therefore `radius` has been overwritten afterwards again with its default value.

Thanks for you help anyway!